# Wordpress form with multiple submit options

Tags: wordpress, forms

I am coding a wordppress page with form with multiple submissions.

So on click of submit 1 a mail has to be sent with the details of form. On click of button 2 the data of the form must to sent to different page and mail has to be sent to admin.

Is there any plugin which serves my purpose.

I tried to use contact form 7 but did not find multiple submissions.

Comment: Make your own plugin or page template

Comment: You can do it into custom template by call separate java script which perform particular action on click of submit button..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Thought there is any tweak in plugin.

Comment: I dont think you will find this functionality out of the box in any plugin, but you can you can use some hooks to add more functionality to cf7. http://xaviesteve.com/3298/wordpress-contact-form-7-hook-unofficial-developer-documentation-and-examples/